# Kubernetes - kubeadm join - Connection refused after new control plane joined

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, etcd

**Issue**

I am trying to join a second control-plane node to a K8S cluster. The first node has a IP of 10.1.50.4 where the second node has a IP of 10.1.50.5. There is a load balancer Virtual IP for the control-plane nodes of 10.1.50.250.

K8S Version: 1.20.1-00

**Command**

```
kubeadm join 10.1.50.4:6443 --token ozlhby.pbi2v5kp0x8ix9cl --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:7aff9979cace02a9f1e98d82253ef9a8c1594c80ea0860aba6ef628xdx7103fb --control-plane --certificate-key 3606aa528cd7d730efafcf535625577d6fx77x7cb6f90e5a8517a807065672d --v=5
```

**Output**

```
I0112 02:20:39.801195   30603 join.go:395] [preflight] found NodeName empty; using OS hostname as NodeName
I0112 02:20:39.801669   30603 join.go:399] [preflight] found advertiseAddress empty; using default interface's IP address as advertiseAddress
I0112 02:20:39.802091   30603 initconfiguration.go:104] detected and using CRI socket: /var/run/dockershim.sock
I0112 02:20:39.802715   30603 interface.go:400] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I0112 02:20:39.802998   30603 interface.go:405] Default route transits interface "ens160"
I0112 02:20:39.803501   30603 interface.go:208] Interface ens160 is up
I0112 02:20:39.803739   30603 interface.go:256] Interface "ens160" has 2 addresses :[10.1.50.5/24 fe80::20c:29ff:fe2d:674d/64].
I0112 02:20:39.803903   30603 interface.go:223] Checking addr  10.1.50.5/24.
I0112 02:20:39.804074   30603 interface.go:230] IP found 10.1.50.5
I0112 02:20:39.804230   30603 interface.go:262] Found valid IPv4 address 10.1.50.5 for interface "ens160".
I0112 02:20:39.804356   30603 interface.go:411] Found active IP 10.1.50.5 
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
I0112 02:20:39.804727   30603 preflight.go:90] [preflight] Running general checks
I0112 02:20:39.804935   30603 checks.go:249] validating the existence and emptiness of directory /etc/kubernetes/manifests
I0112 02:20:39.805227   30603 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
I0112 02:20:39.805375   30603 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf
I0112 02:20:39.805501   30603 checks.go:102] validating the container runtime
I0112 02:20:39.957746   30603 checks.go:128] validating if the "docker" service is enabled and active
        [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
I0112 02:20:40.118312   30603 checks.go:335] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
I0112 02:20:40.118439   30603 checks.go:335] validating the contents of file /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
I0112 02:20:40.118525   30603 checks.go:649] validating whether swap is enabled or not
I0112 02:20:40.118634   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable conntrack
I0112 02:20:40.118786   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ip
I0112 02:20:40.118920   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable iptables
I0112 02:20:40.118991   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable mount
I0112 02:20:40.119140   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable nsenter
I0112 02:20:40.119218   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ebtables
I0112 02:20:40.119310   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable ethtool
I0112 02:20:40.119369   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable socat
I0112 02:20:40.119434   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable tc
I0112 02:20:40.119508   30603 checks.go:376] validating the presence of executable touch
I0112 02:20:40.119601   30603 checks.go:520] running all checks
I0112 02:20:40.274926   30603 checks.go:406] checking whether the given node name is reachable using net.LookupHost
I0112 02:20:40.275311   30603 checks.go:618] validating kubelet version
I0112 02:20:40.459593   30603 checks.go:128] validating if the "kubelet" service is enabled and active
I0112 02:20:40.489282   30603 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 10250
I0112 02:20:40.489826   30603 checks.go:432] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
I0112 02:20:40.490313   30603 join.go:465] [preflight] Discovering cluster-info
I0112 02:20:40.490582   30603 token.go:78] [discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "10.1.50.4:6443"
I0112 02:20:40.511725   30603 token.go:116] [discovery] Requesting info from "10.1.50.4:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned public key
I0112 02:20:40.527163   30603 token.go:133] [discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid and TLS certificate validates against pinned roots, will use API Server "10.1.50.4:6443"
I0112 02:20:40.527277   30603 discovery.go:51] [discovery] Using provided TLSBootstrapToken as authentication credentials for the join process
I0112 02:20:40.527323   30603 join.go:479] [preflight] Fetching init configuration
I0112 02:20:40.527372   30603 join.go:517] [preflight] Retrieving KubeConfig objects
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
I0112 02:20:40.561702   30603 interface.go:400] Looking for default routes with IPv4 addresses
I0112 02:20:40.561742   30603 interface.go:405] Default route transits interface "ens160"
I0112 02:20:40.562257   30603 interface.go:208] Interface ens160 is up
I0112 02:20:40.562548   30603 interface.go:256] Interface "ens160" has 2 addresses :[10.1.50.5/24 fe80::20c:29ff:fe2d:674d/64].
I0112 02:20:40.562680   30603 interface.go:223] Checking addr  10.1.50.5/24.
I0112 02:20:40.562745   30603 interface.go:230] IP found 10.1.50.5
I0112 02:20:40.562774   30603 interface.go:262] Found valid IPv4 address 10.1.50.5 for interface "ens160".
I0112 02:20:40.562800   30603 interface.go:411] Found active IP 10.1.50.5 
I0112 02:20:40.576707   30603 preflight.go:101] [preflight] Running configuration dependant checks
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks before initializing the new control plane instance
I0112 02:20:40.577061   30603 checks.go:577] validating Kubernetes and kubeadm version
I0112 02:20:40.577369   30603 checks.go:166] validating if the firewall is enabled and active
I0112 02:20:40.598127   30603 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 6443
I0112 02:20:40.598485   30603 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 10259
I0112 02:20:40.598744   30603 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 10257
I0112 02:20:40.598987   30603 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
I0112 02:20:40.599271   30603 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml
I0112 02:20:40.599481   30603 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml
I0112 02:20:40.599533   30603 checks.go:286] validating the existence of file /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml
I0112 02:20:40.599686   30603 checks.go:432] validating if the connectivity type is via proxy or direct
I0112 02:20:40.599762   30603 checks.go:471] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0112 02:20:40.600028   30603 checks.go:471] validating http connectivity to first IP address in the CIDR
I0112 02:20:40.600350   30603 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 2379
I0112 02:20:40.600510   30603 checks.go:201] validating availability of port 2380
I0112 02:20:40.600840   30603 checks.go:249] validating the existence and emptiness of directory /var/lib/etcd
[preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
[preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
[preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
I0112 02:20:40.699836   30603 checks.go:839] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.20.1
I0112 02:20:40.796995   30603 checks.go:839] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-controller-manager:v1.20.1
I0112 02:20:40.889726   30603 checks.go:839] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler:v1.20.1
I0112 02:20:40.977887   30603 checks.go:839] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.20.1
I0112 02:20:41.072019   30603 checks.go:839] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2
I0112 02:20:41.164679   30603 checks.go:839] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/etcd:3.4.13-0
I0112 02:20:41.255987   30603 checks.go:839] image exists: k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.7.0
[download-certs] Downloading the certificates in Secret "kubeadm-certs" in the "kube-system" Namespace
[certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
I0112 02:20:41.270660   30603 certs.go:45] creating PKI assets
I0112 02:20:41.271129   30603 certs.go:474] validating certificate period for ca certificate
[certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
[certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8s-master-1 kube.local kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.1.50.5 10.1.50.250]
I0112 02:20:42.284014   30603 certs.go:474] validating certificate period for front-proxy-ca certificate
[certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
I0112 02:20:42.412481   30603 certs.go:474] validating certificate period for etcd/ca certificate
[certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8s-master-1 localhost] and IPs [10.1.50.5 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
[certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [k8s-master-1 localhost] and IPs [10.1.50.5 127.0.0.1 ::1]
[certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
[certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
[certs] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
I0112 02:20:44.631172   30603 certs.go:76] creating new public/private key files for signing service account users
[certs] Using the existing "sa" key
[kubeconfig] Generating kubeconfig files
[kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
[kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
[kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
[control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
I0112 02:20:45.370294   30603 manifests.go:96] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
I0112 02:20:45.370640   30603 certs.go:474] validating certificate period for CA certificate
I0112 02:20:45.370743   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0112 02:20:45.370767   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0112 02:20:45.370779   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0112 02:20:45.370790   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0112 02:20:45.370802   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-apiserver"
I0112 02:20:45.381917   30603 manifests.go:126] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-apiserver" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.381975   30603 manifests.go:96] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
I0112 02:20:45.382292   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "ca-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.382324   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "etc-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.382336   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "flexvolume-dir" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.382347   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "k8s-certs" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.382357   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.382367   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-local-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.382377   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "usr-share-ca-certificates" for component "kube-controller-manager"
I0112 02:20:45.383243   30603 manifests.go:126] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-controller-manager" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml"
[control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
I0112 02:20:45.383285   30603 manifests.go:96] [control-plane] getting StaticPodSpecs
I0112 02:20:45.383551   30603 manifests.go:109] [control-plane] adding volume "kubeconfig" for component "kube-scheduler"
I0112 02:20:45.384124   30603 manifests.go:126] [control-plane] wrote static Pod manifest for component "kube-scheduler" to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml"
[check-etcd] Checking that the etcd cluster is healthy
I0112 02:20:45.391793   30603 local.go:80] [etcd] Checking etcd cluster health
I0112 02:20:45.391826   30603 local.go:83] creating etcd client that connects to etcd pods
I0112 02:20:45.391841   30603 etcd.go:177] retrieving etcd endpoints from "kubeadm.kubernetes.io/etcd.advertise-client-urls" annotation in etcd Pods
I0112 02:20:45.436952   30603 etcd.go:101] etcd endpoints read from pods: https://10.1.50.4:2379
I0112 02:20:45.467237   30603 etcd.go:247] etcd endpoints read from etcd: https://10.1.50.4:2379
I0112 02:20:45.467292   30603 etcd.go:119] update etcd endpoints: https://10.1.50.4:2379
I0112 02:20:45.497258   30603 kubelet.go:110] [kubelet-start] writing bootstrap kubelet config file at /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf
I0112 02:20:45.499069   30603 kubelet.go:139] [kubelet-start] Checking for an existing Node in the cluster with name "k8s-master-1" and status "Ready"
I0112 02:20:45.506135   30603 kubelet.go:153] [kubelet-start] Stopping the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
[kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
[kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
[kubelet-start] Waiting for the kubelet to perform the TLS Bootstrap...
I0112 02:20:50.940170   30603 cert_rotation.go:137] Starting client certificate rotation controller
I0112 02:20:50.946669   30603 kubelet.go:188] [kubelet-start] preserving the crisocket information for the node
I0112 02:20:50.946719   30603 patchnode.go:30] [patchnode] Uploading the CRI Socket information "/var/run/dockershim.sock" to the Node API object "k8s-master-1" as an annotation
I0112 02:21:01.078081   30603 local.go:148] creating etcd client that connects to etcd pods
I0112 02:21:01.078135   30603 etcd.go:177] retrieving etcd endpoints from "kubeadm.kubernetes.io/etcd.advertise-client-urls" annotation in etcd Pods
I0112 02:21:01.130781   30603 etcd.go:101] etcd endpoints read from pods: https://10.1.50.4:2379
I0112 02:21:01.240220   30603 etcd.go:247] etcd endpoints read from etcd: https://10.1.50.4:2379
I0112 02:21:01.240255   30603 etcd.go:119] update etcd endpoints: https://10.1.50.4:2379
I0112 02:21:01.240812   30603 local.go:156] [etcd] Getting the list of existing members
I0112 02:21:01.282237   30603 local.go:164] [etcd] Checking if the etcd member already exists: https://10.1.50.5:2380
I0112 02:21:01.282791   30603 local.go:175] [etcd] Adding etcd member: https://10.1.50.5:2380
[etcd] Announced new etcd member joining to the existing etcd cluster
I0112 02:21:01.370283   30603 local.go:182] Updated etcd member list: [{k8s-master-1 https://10.1.50.5:2380} {k8s-master-0 https://10.1.50.4:2380}]
[etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for "etcd"
[etcd] Waiting for the new etcd member to join the cluster. This can take up to 40s
I0112 02:21:01.372930   30603 etcd.go:488] [etcd] attempting to see if all cluster endpoints ([https://10.1.50.4:2379 https://10.1.50.5:2379]) are available 1/8
I0112 02:21:03.455137   30603 etcd.go:468] Failed to get etcd status for https://10.1.50.5:2379: failed to dial endpoint https://10.1.50.5:2379 with maintenance client: context deadline exceeded
[upload-config] Storing the configuration used in ConfigMap "kubeadm-config" in the "kube-system" Namespace
[mark-control-plane] Marking the node k8s-master-1 as control-plane by adding the labels "node-role.kubernetes.io/master=''" and "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane='' (deprecated)"
[mark-control-plane] Marking the node k8s-master-1 as control-plane by adding the taints [node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule]

This node has joined the cluster and a new control plane instance was created:

* Certificate signing request was sent to apiserver and approval was received.
* The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details.
* Control plane (master) label and taint were applied to the new node.
* The Kubernetes control plane instances scaled up.
* A new etcd member was added to the local/stacked etcd cluster.

To start administering your cluster from this node, you need to run the following as a regular user:

        mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
        sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
        sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

Run 'kubectl get nodes' to see this node join the cluster.
```

**Network Tests - 10.1.50.4**

`kubectl get nodes`

[image]

10.1.50.4 > `lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

[image]

Installed etcd-client and ran `etcdctl member list` (after 10.1.50.5 tried to join)

[image]

`etcdctl cluster-health` (after 10.1.50.5 tried to join)

[image]

`systemctl restart network` (after 10.1.50.5 tried to join)

[image]

`etcdctl --version` (after 10.1.50.5 tried to join)

[image]

`kubeadm version` (after 10.1.50.5 tried to join)

[image]

`kubectl get nodes (after 10.1.50.5 tried to join)`

[image]

**Network Tests - 10.1.50.5 - Before Join**

`route -n`

[image]

`nmap -p 6443 10.1.50.4`

[image]

`ping 10.1.50.4`

[image]

`ping 10.1.50.250`

[image]

**Network Tests - 10.1.50.5 - After Join**

`route -n`

Same

`nmap -p 6443 10.1.50.4`

[image]

`ping 10.1.50.4`

Same

`ping 10.1.50.250`

Same

**Edit**

Command `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-744cfdf676-vf6fw   1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   calico-node-plsv4                          1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-btdsr                    1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   coredns-74ff55c5b-q66c9                    1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   etcd-k8s-master-0                          1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-k8s-master-0                1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-k8s-master-0       1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   kube-proxy-7jqx9                           1/1     Running   0          47h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-k8s-master-0                1/1     Running   0          47h
```

Command `docker exec -it k8s_POD_etcd-k8s-master-0_kube-system_a9f805c0eb22e024f35cb6a5e3768516_0 etcdctl --endpoints=https://10.1.50.4:2379 --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt member list`

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"etcdctl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

Comment: Could you run `etcdctl cluster-health`, then `systemctl restart network` and again `etcdctl cluster-health` ? Please also check `etcdctl --version` and `kubeadm version`.

Comment: @mario Updated the question with the results of those queries.

Comment: See this question https://serverfault.com/questions/1050868/kubernetes-oci-runtime-exec-failed-starting-container-process-caused-exec

Comment: This question is more geared towards your issue. https://serverfault.com/questions/1050868/kubernetes-oci-runtime-exec-failed-starting-container-process-caused-exec

Answer (score 1):

Command

```
docker exec -it k8s_POD_etcd-<nodename>_kube-system_<docker container id> etcdctl --endpoints=https://<node ip>:2379 --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt member list
```

Response

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"etcdctl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

This question is more qeared towards your issue.

[Kubernetes OCI runtime exec failed - starting container process caused "exec: \"etcdctl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050868/kubernetes-oci-runtime-exec-failed-starting-container-process-caused-exec)

Answer (score 0):

Has the node 10.1.50.5 or a node with this IP/Name already been joined to the cluster and then removed again? If yes you have to remove the entrys 10.1.50.5 (or nodename) in the etcd (not via kubeadm/kubectl). Or you change the 10.1.50.5 IP address to e.g. 10.1.50.55 and try to join again.

For configuring etcd you have to logon to etcd. e.g. this command (can also be achieved with kubectl exec)

```
docker exec -it k8s_etcd_etcd-10.1.50.4...COMPLETEPODNAME \
  etcdctl --endpoints=https://10.1.50.4:2379 \
  --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key  \
  --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt  \
  --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt member list

etcdctl member remove MEMBERUUID
```

Comment: Got the full container name by running this `docker container ls | grep k8s_POD_etcd`. Comes back with a runtime exec error.

Comment: The OCI error appeared because of a missing `etcdctl` I think (beginning of 2nd line of the example)

Comment: @Gerd Yep, updated the command and its output. Still a OCI error but with the $PATH this time.