# Kubernetes OCI runtime exec failed - starting container process caused "exec: \"etcdctl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes, etcd

**Background**

Created a fresh Kubernetes cluster using `kubeadm init --config /home/kube/kubeadmn-config.yaml --upload-certs` and then joining the 2nd control plane node by running the below.

```
kubeadm join VIP:6443 --token <token> \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<hash> \
    --control-plane --certificate-key <key> \
    --v=5
```

**Question**

Is etcdctl commands supposed to come back with a return value? Either using the command directly or using the docker exec method shown below. I have these packages installed kubeadm, kubectl, kubelet, and docker.

Kubectl version: 1.20.1
OS: Ubuntu 18.04

***Commands from the first node***

Command

```
etcdctl cluster-health
```

Response

```
cluster may be unhealthy: failed to list members
Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured; error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connect: connection refused
; error #1: EOF

error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: connect: connection refused
error #1: EOF
```

Command

```
docker container ls | grep k8s_POD_etcd
```

Response

```
k8s_POD_etcd-<nodename>_kube-system_<docker container id>
```

Command

```
docker exec -it k8s_POD_etcd-<nodename>_kube-system_<docker container id> etcdctl --endpoints=https://<node ip>:2379 --key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key --cert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --cacert=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt member list
```

Response

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"etcdctl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

**EDIT**

Upgraded to v3.2 etcdctl API

Command

```
etcdctl endpoint status
```

Response

```
Failed to get the status of endpoint 127.0.0.1:2379 (context deadline exceeded)
```

Comment: Hi PieDev, welcome to S.F. That 4001 port is the legacy one, used by etcd2 which is almost certainly not supported by k8s; I would guess it's either an ancient binary or is missing `ETCDCTL_API=3` and the associated --endpoints (`ETCDCTL_ENDPOINTS`) values to point it to the modern :2379 port. I would further guess the etcd certs are volume mounted from `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd` on the host, and thus you don't need etcdctl to exist inside the docker image, you can use the system version

Comment: @PieDev Any progress?

Comment: @mdaniel See the edit I made. I do see .crt and .key files in `ls -l /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/`.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor See the edit I made.

Comment: Did @Matt answer help you to solve your problem?If yes,Please consider accepting and up voting it. [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 1):

The error mentioned by OP is caused by non existing etcdctl exacutable in container.

Why? Because he used the wrong container. Look at the following command:

```
docker container ls | grep k8s_POD_etcd
be510c179ced   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"  2 days ago  Up 2 days   k8s_POD_etcd-minikube_kube-system_2315889f8b2b54f1b9d43feafe941d01_0
```

Notice the container is `k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2`. It's not an etcd container.

But why?? what is this pause container? I won't answer this question because somebody already answered it here: [what-are-the-pause-containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651269/what-are-the-pause-containers).

I will try to answer a better question: Where is the actual etcd container?

Let's have a look at the output of the same command but with slightly modified grep command; lets grep for `etcd`:

```
docker container ls | grep etcd
c989e7d1d25b   0369cf4303ff           "etcd --advertise-cl…"   2 days ago       Up 2 days k8s_etcd_etcd-minikube_kube-system_2315889f8b2b54f1b9d43feafe941d01_0
be510c179ced   k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2   "/pause"                 2 days ago       Up 2 days k8s_POD_etcd-minikube_kube-system_2315889f8b2b54f1b9d43feafe941d01_0
```

Now we have two lines of output, one is the previously found pause container, and the second one is our etcd container with a name starting with `k8s_etcd_etcd`.
Let's see if we can run docker exec on this container:

```
$ docker exec -it k8s_etcd_etcd-<nodename>_kube-system_<docker container id> etcdctl version
etcdctl version: 3.4.13
API version: 3.4
```

Yes, we can!

---

To summarize: it looks like you were looking at the wrong container from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The `context deadline exceeded` is an unclear error returned by `grpc` client when it can't establish the connection. If you want to see the exact error message you should set `ETCDCTL_API=2` (more details on that can be found [here](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/10087)).

The cert/key pairs in `/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/` should look something like this:

```
# ls -l /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/
total 32
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1017 Nov 12 15:32 ca.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1679 Nov 12 15:32 ca.key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1094 Nov 12 15:32 healthcheck-client.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1675 Nov 12 15:32 healthcheck-client.key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1180 Nov 12 15:32 peer.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1675 Nov 12 15:32 peer.key
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1180 Nov 12 15:32 server.crt
-rw-------    1 root     root          1679 Nov 12 15:32 server.key

# etcdctl --version
etcdctl version: 3.3.1
API version: 2

# ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl snapshot save snapshot.db \
  --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt \
  --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt \
  --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.key
Snapshot saved at snapshot.db

# ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --write-out=table snapshot status snapshot.db
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
|   HASH   | REVISION | TOTAL KEYS | TOTAL SIZE |
+----------+----------+------------+------------+
| b9d500f7 |    72966 |       1194 |     4.9 MB |
```

Make sure that you apply [the right cert/key pair](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/10642#issuecomment-554297207). Also, [this guide](https://medium.com/@shoaibjdev/etcdctl-error-context-deadline-exceeded-accessing-etcd-control-in-newer-versions-of-kubernetes-ef78c83be6ce) can help you out.

Note that etcd takes several certificate related configuration options, either through command-line flags or environment variables. The basic setup for it can be found [here](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/v3.4.0/Documentation/op-guide/security.md#basic-setup).

Comment: @PieDev Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: @PieDev If the above does not solve your issue than please edit your question and provide the output from `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` and `kubectl -n kube-system describe pod etcd` to verify if etcd is running in you k8s cluster. Also, what was your `kubeadm init` config in terms of the etcd?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using alpine try

```
docker exec -it <container-id> sh
```

It can happen due to an ordering mistake
You might need to run use /bin/bash or /bin/sh, depending on the shell in your container.

The reason is documented in the ReleaseNotes file of Git and it is well explained here - [Bash in Git for Windows: Weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357813/bash-in-git-for-windows-weirdness-when-running-a-command-with-cmd-exe-c-with-a)

[some more solution:](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1621490)